# regarding install python modules locally and make it searchable by centrailized managed development environment

Tags: python, linux

I am working on a development environment that is administrated by third party, which does not allow me to install the packages as what I want, such as using  pip install graphviz

As a result, I download `graphviz-0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl` into my local directory. What are the ways that I can let this whl file be used by the python development environment. Or how can I let the local path of whl file be searchable by publically maintained python environment?

Comment: You should look into [How to write a setup.py file](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html)

Comment: do you have access to virtualenv?